# Typescript non empty object with unknown properties

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to define a type that allows for a object with any properties, but enforces having at least 1 (unknown) property?

```js
// this does not work

type Test = {
  [key: string]: any
}

const obj: Test = {} // this should give an error
const anotherObj: Test = { something: "thing" } // this should work
```

Comment: You can see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks

Comment: @FahdLihidheb how is this useful? Do you have a solution?

Comment: @Tobias S. use a factory to create your Test objects and check in creation if there is at least one key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the only solution I can think of (Thanks to the comment of @Fahd Lihidheb)

```
type NotEmpty<T> = keyof T extends never ? never : T

function createTest<T extends {[key: string]: any}>(test: NotEmpty<T>): T {
  return test
}

const obj = createTest({})                            // error
const anotherObj = createTest({ something: "thing" }) // works
```

I don't think it is possible with just a `type` definition. We have to use a factory method instead so we can `infer` the type of `T` and check if any keys exist.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon a possible answer when working on something else.

```js
type NonEmptyObj<T extends Record<string, unknown>> = T extends Record<string, never> ? never : T;
```

This relies on `Record<string, never>` which defines an empty object. We check if T never extends an empty object.

Utilizing this test would look something like this:

```js
function someFunction<T extends Record<string, unknown>>(foo: NonEmptyObject<T>) { ... }
```

[TS playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gOwKIFsygPICMBWAeAFSggA9gIEATAZygCUIBjOAJ0r2uBYEsEBzADRQArggDWCOAHcEAPllQAvFCKlyVWg2ZsOXXoKgIIANwgsFAfkMmzUAFwqA3AChnAM1GNg3RFGpwUCAAxT29EQmIyChp6JlZ2Th5%20IVEJaTlZAAo3ODgHeGQ0TFxCWQBKKABvZygoFghgYRYEKBy4R1rnAF9Xf0CQhC8fBEzKrrLnPuDQ4dGoLABDFgcAIkWWFahxyYDpwbCRtaWVsqA)

Should you do this? Probably not. The error provided by this typing is quite unhelpful and the possible use-case very niche.